# Yii2 Display Data from the Database Without Using GridView

Tags: php, gridview, yii2

I have this `GridView` widget in my `index.php` view:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        //'user_id',
        'fname',
        'lname',
        'username',
        // 'password',
        // 'user_type',
        // 'creator',             
    ],
]); ?>
```

It obviously generates a table containing data from my database table. I want to get rid of the `GridView` widget and use other means of displaying data from the database. How do I do that?

One of the reasons why I don't want to use the `GridView` widget is that I want the display to *not* look like a table. Something like this, for example:

[image]

Is there any way? Thanks.

Comment: Did you check ListView widget? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-listview.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [ListView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-listview.html) widget for these purposes.

Example of basic usage:

```
<?= ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'itemView' => '_view',    
]) ?>
```

In `_view` view file you should place layout for a single user. Inside you can access the current user model through `$model` variable and get desired attributes values. Read more in official docs.

Comment: thanks! at first I used `DetailView` but I can't seem to customize it. now I just put `<?= $model->fname; ?>` and so on, now I can customize it whatever I want.

Comment: `DetailView` is for single model.

Answer (score 3):

You can get the models in this way:

```
$myModels = $dataProvider->getModels();
```

and then iterate through $myModels array to access individual instances and manage the fields with html formatting you prefer